# SQL to return one row with columns in another table, if a corresponding row exists in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in a database, `a` & `b`.

Table `b` has a foreign key that references a column on `a`.

I'm trying to figure out how to get a single row from `b` with all of the columns from it's corresponding `a`.  However, not all of `b`'s rows will have corresponding rows in `a`.

The following SQL will return all rows in `b` that have corresponding rows in `a` with all the columns from both tables.

`"SELECT * FROM b INNER JOIN a ON b.foo = a.foo`

But I just want one row where `b.foo` equals some value with it's corresponding columns from a (if any).

So, naively:

`"SELECT * FROM b INNER JOIN a ON b.foo = a.foo WHERE b.foo = 'some value'`

The problem is, this sometimes returns no rows since there may not be a corresponding row in `a`. But we are guaranteed that some row in `b` exists where `b.foo` equals `some value`, and that should always be returned.

Is there a SQL command that can always return one row in b (given that the row in `b` exists) either with the corresponding columns in `a` or if a corresponding `a` does not exist, just the columns in `b`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` you will *always* receive the `b` row, and the `a` column values will be NULL if no matching row was found.